# AWS CDK: How to access VPC in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I need access to resources in my staging/prod accounts' VPC from my "tools" account (I have an RDS instance sitting in each of both VPCs and want to automate schema upgrades as part of my CI/CD).

How can I import a VPC from the staging/prod account within a stack in the "tools" accounts?

[`Vpc.fromLookup()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#importing-an-existing-vpc) does not work since it searches for VPCs in the stack's region and account, but not in other regions/accounts.

**EDIT:**

I want to give a CodeBuild project (part of a CodePipeline) in the "tools" account access to the RDS instance in the VPC of the prod/staging accounts.
To give it access, I use the [`vpc` attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-codebuild-readme.html#definition-of-vpc-configuration-in-codebuild-project) on the CodeBuild project.

I'm not sure what's the best way to tackle schema upgrades using CodePipeline/CodeBuild.
Ideally, the RDS instance should be sitting in a private/isolated subnet.

```js
const dbMigrateBuild = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'MigrateBuild', {
  buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename('buildspec-migrate.yml'),
  environment: {
    buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_4_0,
  },
  environmentVariables: {
    migrationBucketId: {
      type: codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
      value: sourceOutput.bucketName,
    },
    dbEndpoint: {
      type: codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
      value: dbEndpoint,
    },
    dbSecretId: {
      type: codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
      value: dbSecretId,
    },
  },
  vpc: ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'Vpc', { vpcId }), // <-- this is not working
});

// dbMigrateBuild.connections.allowToDefaultPort(db); // how to grant permission ??

const dbMigrateAction = new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
  actionName: 'Db_Migrate',
  project: dbMigrateBuild,
  input: sourceOutput,
  runOrder: 130,
});
```

Comment: Do you mean, how to establish a VPC peering between two VPCs in different accounts?

Comment: @Marcin I added more details to my question. I don't have a VPC setup in my tools account.

Comment: You can't "import" a VPC from a different account into your account. However, you can establish a vpc-peering connection to a VPC from different account. This will allow you to access resources in the peered VPC, from your VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you would need to do one of the following:

- Assume a role from the "other account".
- Use the credentials from assuming this role to retrieve your values, by performing an [export of the variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) on the CLI.

This has to be performed before you run the cdk commands, using the sts [assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) command.